# Listview dentro de un Scrollview no hace scroll cuando la lista es más grande que el layout

Tags: android, android-layout, scroll, android-listview

Buenas,

Tengo un problema con un `listview` dentro de un `scrollview`, no consigo la manera de hacer que haga `scroll` cuando el `listview` es muy grande.
He mirado mucho sobre la cómo solucionarlo pero no veo el porqué a mi no me funciona.

Se supone que dentro del `scrollview` tiene que haber un `linearlayout` para que no de problemas, pues con o sin `linearlayout` a mi no me hace `scroll`.

Este es mi código en el xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="radio.ecca.gesenecca.NotasActivity"
android:background="@color/grey100">

<!-- Toolbar -->
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/appbarNotas"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include
        layout="@layout/toolbar_calificaciones_down"
        android:elevation="4dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/cursoacademico"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            style="@style/Calificaciones.Toolbar"/>

        <Spinner android:id="@+id/CmbYearToolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"

            android:popupBackground="#FFFFFF"/>

        <TextView
            android:text="@string/filtros"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            style="@style/Calificaciones.Toolbar"/>

        <Spinner android:id="@+id/CmbFilterToolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:popupBackground="#FFFFFF"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/lvCalificaciones"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/grey500">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:padding="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Ahora mismo me siento cómo un tonto al no ver el error.
Espero que me iluminen en mi camino, un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: El `ListView` no necesita un `scroll` en todo caso puedes usar sus funciones para que el `scroll` tome otra apariencia.

Comment: veo que agregar un layout : toolbar_calificaciones_down.xml es importante agregarlos.

Comment: Añade el código del adaptador, todo indica que el problema estará allí: CalificacionesAdapter.java

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el CoordinatorLayout por un FrameLayout a ver si te cambia el comportamiento, también veo que tienes 2 Toolbars en el layout, por lo demás no acabo de ver que puede ser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListView` ya tiene su propio scroll, elimina tu `ScrollView` y deja solo el `ListView`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="radio.ecca.gesenecca.NotasActivity"
    android:background="@color/grey100">

    <!-- Toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/appbarNotas"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar_calificaciones_down"
            android:elevation="4dp"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/cursoacademico"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:paddingLeft="5dp"
                style="@style/Calificaciones.Toolbar"/>

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/CmbYearToolbar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"

                android:popupBackground="#FFFFFF"/>

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/filtros"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                style="@style/Calificaciones.Toolbar"/>

            <Spinner android:id="@+id/CmbFilterToolbar"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:popupBackground="#FFFFFF"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvCalificaciones"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:smoothScrollbar="true"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@color/grey500">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:text="@string/lorem_ipsum"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Añade el código de tu adaptador y el layout de la vista del item que añades en cada row del ListView para ver que puede ser. Un ListView normal si añades vistas comunes no da ningún problema con el scroll

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta, prueba con el adaptador que indico

Comment: Vale he visto algo que no me cuadraba en la Activity, prueba la Actvity que he puesto

Comment: Disculpa lo había 'traducido' al inglés, además me había dejado dos linea. Comprueba el último código ahora

Comment: Por último te propongo que pruebes otro tipo de adaptador que extienda de BaseAdapter, aquí puedes ver como: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-a-BaseAdapter-with-ListView

Answer (score 1):

No es un código muy recomendable de usar a menos que conozcas el escenario perfecto. Por ejemplo el dispositivo en el que vas a estar utilizando la App. Te Permitirá modificar el alto del listview dinámicamente de acuerdo al número de filas que tengas.

```
    int ancho = 1200; //Por ejemplo 1200. puedes jugar con estos números
    int altoItem= 120; //Dependiendo del tamaño de alto de cada item (Fila)
    int alto = (lvCalificaciones.getAdapter().getCount())*altoItem; 

    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ancho, alto);
    lvCalificaciones.setLayoutParams(params);
```